# Google Map API is not working with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript, google-maps-api-3

I am facing an issue with Google Map API. I have included the google map API CDN in my **index.html** file as shown below :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&language=de" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But it give an error in console that is mentioned below

```
'google is not defined'
```

than I have included the Google MAP CDN to the **vendor.ts** file of a webpack. After that,I can see a global **window.google** object but it doesn't have any function attached to it.

> Please refer the screenshot of correct console and incorrect console.

**Correct Image**
[image: correct image]

**Incorrect Image**
[image: incorrect image]

Here is my **package.json** file

```
 { 
 "name": "angular2-webpack",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "A webpack starter for Angular",
 "scripts": {
   "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
   "test": "karma start",
   "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail"
 },
 "license": "MIT",
 "dependencies": {
   "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
   "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
   "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
   "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
   "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
  "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "dragula": "^3.7.2",
  "fullcalendar": "^3.0.1",
  "highcharts": "^5.0.9",
  "jquery": "^3.1.1",
  "jquery-mousewheel": "^3.1.13",
  "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
  "moment": "^2.17.1",
  "ng2-dragula": "^1.3.0",
  "primeng": "^2.0.2",
  "rxjs": "5.0.1",
  "webpack-strip": "^0.1.0",
  "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
  "@types/jquery": "^2.0.41",
  "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
  "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
  "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.4",
  "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0-beta.5",
  "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
  "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.16.1",
  "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
  "karma": "^1.2.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
  "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
  "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
  "karma-webpack": "^2.0.1",
  "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
  "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
  "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
  "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
  "typescript": "~2.2.2",
  "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
  "webpack": "2.2.1",
  "webpack-bundle-size-analyzer": "^2.6.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.1",
  "webpack-merge": "^3.0.0"
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you imported google dependency in your component..??

Comment: @MukulSharma can you tell me , what kind of dependency ?

Comment: some thing like - npm install Google-Map

Comment: @MukulSharma , I have tried it but it doesn't works for me.

Comment: Have you set a valid API key from Google Maps API?